# Can't generate cucumber reports after stop cypress runner

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am using Cypress + Cucumber. Trying to fail test and skip steps if one of the failed. For this, I'm using the following code:

```
afterEach(function () {
    if (this.currentTest.state === 'failed') {
        Cypress.runner.stop()
    }
});
```

But if I use this and test failed I don't receive any reports in cucumber-json folder. Maybe someone has a solution for this?

Comment: If a test fails, remaining steps are automatically skipped. So what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Adding to the previous comment, is your expected outcome that if one test fails, all other tests are skipped and you still get a Cucumber Report with the tests run up to that point?

Comment: I don't know about the author but I am facing exactly the same problem @Sebastino Vierk. I am trying to stop the run if one test fails. Still I want to see where the failure was in the html report. Any ideas how to get that?